# pymssql on mac os x mountain lion 10.9.2

Tags: macos, python-3.x, osx-mountain-lion, pymssql

Recently discovered pymssql and got it working on a windows machine (python 3.4).  However when I try to run the script on my mac (10.9.2), I get an error when I 'import pymssql'.  Note both on the windows box and on the mac, I installed via 'pip3.4 install pymssql'.  Installation concluded with no errors in both cases.

This is what I get when I try to import pymssql on the mac :

Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 15 2014, 23:02:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pymssql
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymssql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
> > >         Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymssql.so
> > >         Reason: image not found

Note pip3.4 search pymssql results in : 
pymssql                   - DB-API interface to Microsoft SQL Server for
                            Python. (new Cython-based version)
  INSTALLED: 2.1.0 (latest)

Note further that /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib does NOT exist, but then again, I couldn't find in on the windows box either (searched the C drive for libsybdb)

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install freetds library to talk to Microsoft SQL Server

```
brew install freetds
```